# Symfony access control for site root

Tags: php, symfony, firewall, access-control

I have created a site with firewall access controls that force users to log in to access any content i.e.

```
 - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

Now the client wants a splash page at the root of the website i.e www.sitename.com.

I have this page mapped to `DefaultController::indexAction`, however I cannot work out how to allow `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` access to this page as there is no path name i.e `www.sitename.com/splash-page` to hang the access control off.

Can I even do this?

Comment: Does your website use *folders* in the paths? You can secure all the parts of your website except the homepage: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#authorization

Comment: Thanks for you prompt reply.  I am not sure what you mean by folders - if you mean urls that mimic a directory structure or have some form of hierarchy i.e. blog/individual-piece-of-content then no.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, *folders* was not the right word. Anyway I think that you can still secure pages by adding the name of your pages, eg. `- { path: ^/mypage, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }`. Do it for every page with the exception of the homepage. It should work even if there is no *folders*.

Comment: And don't forget to remove restriction in your login page, otherwise users won't be able to access to this page in order to log in.

Comment: Thanks - thought that might be what I would have to do - but was hoping there was a quicker way than going through and doing it page by page.

Comment: This is why the documentation encourages URLs using a hierarchy *folders* and *sub-folders*, it allows to protect a *folder* and its pages with only one rule.

Comment: See my answer, I used a regular expression to reduce the length of the rule.

Answer (score 18):

You can secure all the URLs except the homepage URL:

```yaml
# app/config/security.yml file
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        # Logged in
        - { path: ^/(.+), roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        # no authentication for the homepage:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

The regular expression `^/(.+)` will match every URL than contains something after `/`.

The regular expression `^/$` will match the URL than contains nothing after `/` (`/` is the end of the string).

And the homepage URL have to be declared in a `routing.yml` file:

```yaml
homepage:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: ACMEBundle:Default:homepage }
```

Comment: Hi @nmcilree if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/237701) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.